# miraiマルウェアの感染経路

Tags: security, malware

miraiマルウェアが気になり、様々な記事や実際のコードを読んでみました。

[IoTセキュリティガイドラインの国際標準化動向](https://www.jnsa.org/seminar/2018/1207/data/2018_resume4.pdf#page=31)
[「Mirai」とはどんなウイルス？感染の脅威や仕組み、対策を解説！](https://it-trend.jp/cyber_attack/article/442-0017)

miraiマルウェアは安直なユーザ名とパスワードに設定された機器に対し、辞書攻撃をすることで、IPカメラなどのIoTデバイスに感染することがわかりました。
感染後は、ラテラルムーブメントにより、同じネットワーク内に存在するアドレスに、片っ端から辞書攻撃で感染を拡大させることも分かりました。

ただ気になるのが、**最初に感染する機器はどうやって探し出されるのか**ということです。

浅はかな知識しか持ち合わせていないので、これ以上のことを調べることができませんでした。

最近は、特定のベンダーの機器だけの脆弱性を狙ったキャンペーンも確認されています。

**感染させることのできる端末を探し出すフローを教えていただけたら幸いです。**

Comment: 質問の冒頭に「様々な記事や実際のコードを読んでみました。」とあるので、答えは既に公開されているソースコードに存在するのに、「感染させることのできる端末を探し出すフローを教えていただけたら」というのは婉曲で遠回りな質問だと思われます。自身が調べたソースコードを示し、「そのどの部分が端末を探し出すフローに該当するのか教えて欲しい/あるいはこの部分が該当すると思うが正しいか？」といった風な質問の方が直接的でしょう。ただし「デバッグして欲しい」とか「開発して欲しい」といった問題を丸投げしまう「避けるべき質問」にも見えてしまいますが。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

「miraiマルウェア」で検索すると例えば以下の解説記事がヒットします。

[IoTデバイスを狙うマルウェア「Mirai」とは何か――その正体と対策](https://techfactory.itmedia.co.jp/tf/articles/1704/13/news010.html)

(強調は引用者によるもの)

> まず、Miraiは **ランダムなIPアドレスに対して感染先を探します。** 感染できるデバイスを見つけ出し、感染可能な端末にログインして、ボットをダウンロードさせます。このとき利用されるのが、ソースコード内に設定された“ありがちな「ID」と「パスワード」の組み合わせ”です。

件のマルウェアに限らず、大抵この手の攻撃は適当な IP アドレスに対してのランダムアクセスがほとんどだと思います。(特定企業をターゲットとした攻撃でない限り)

スパムメール等と同じく「下手な鉄砲も数撃ちゃ当たる」理論で、一見非効率っぽく思いますが、現代的な計算機の処理性能を考えればこれで十分なんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。見落としていました。

家庭内にあるIPカメラなどもこれでアクセスされるのでしょうか？
不本意に外部に公開されているIoT機器などに、マルウェアが感染することはわかります。
ですが、家庭内で使うだけならアクセスされることはない(グローバルIPが割り振られていないため)と思うのですが、違うのでしょうか？

Comment: もちろんLAN内だけで使う設定にしたなら外部からアクセス経路はありません。
しかし家庭用IPカメラは外出先からも見れるようにインターネットに接続する運用のほうが普通じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: セキュリティ設定はさておき、「インターネット経由でアクセスできる」から「IoT機器」なんじゃないですかね？そこの前提を勘違いしてる気がします。

Answer (score 0):

企業体レベルで遠隔地に複数台設置したカメラを同時監視したいような場合はカメラそのものに global IP アドレスを振ったりします。

ホームネットワーク内で IP カメラを使っている場合でも真に家庭内イントラネットに閉じているとは限らず、たとえば出先からペットの様子を監視したいみたいな要望をかなえるために

- 設置者の意思でゲートウエイ機器（ホームルーター）のポートを開いた
- カメラ自体に UPnP でゲートウエイ機器のポートを開く機能があるが、設置者がそのことに気づいていない（ので設置者の意図に反してそのカメラは外からアクセスできてしまう状態である）

なんてのはありそうなシナリオです。そういうのを攻撃者は狙うんでしょうね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

やはり、"意思に反して"公開しちゃってるということですね。

こういった攻撃はIDSなどで防げないものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 逸般人ならともかく一般人にそれを求めるのは無理そう。

Answer (score -1):

Miraiに限りせんが、一般的にCAPEC-118配下のような手法を用いて攻撃対象を探すのではないでしょうか。
https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/118.html

- CAPEC-118: 情報の収集と分析

  - CAPEC-116: 発掘
  - CAPEC-117: 傍受
  - CAPEC-169: フットプリンティング
  - CAPEC-224: フィンガープリンティング
  - CAPEC-188: リバースエンジニアリング
  - CAPEC-192: プロトコル解析
  - CAPEC-410: 情報の引き出し